# how to use regex.Matches in c#

Tags: c#, regex

how to use regex.Matches

input string

```
  string strQuery = "BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.year, week_off_day=case when "+
                    "BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='1' then 'Sunday' "+ 
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='2' then 'Monday' "+
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='3' then 'Tuesday' "+
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='4' then 'Wednesday' "+
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='5' then 'Thursday' "+
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='6' then 'Friday' "+
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='7' then 'Saturday' "+
                    "else '' end,"+
                    "BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.year, week_off_day=case when "+
                    "BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='1' then 'Sunday' "+                   
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='2' then 'Monday' "+
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='3' then 'Tuesday' "+ 
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='4' then 'Wednesday' "+  
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='5' then 'Thursday' "+ 
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='6' then 'Friday' "+ 
                    "when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='7' then 'Saturday' "+
                    "else '' end,";
```

my pattern is

```
MatchCollection words = Regex.Matches(strQuery, @"(?i)?<firstMatch>.*,)  (?<secondMatch>[^=]*)=case(?<thirdMatch>.*end\b)");
    foreach (Match word in words)
    {
        strQuery = Regex.Replace(word , @"....", @" ... ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    }
```

issue is its matching only once

i need output like below

```
 BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.year, 
 case 
    when BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='1' then 'Sunday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='2' then 'Monday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='3' then 'Tuesday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='4' then 'Wednesday'  
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='5' then 'Thursday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='6' then 'Friday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='7' then 'Saturday' 
    else '' 
 end **" week_off_day"** ,
 BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.year, 
 case 
    when BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='1' then 'Sunday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='2' then 'Monday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='3' then 'Tuesday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='4' then 'Wednesday'  
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='5' then 'Thursday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='6' then 'Friday' 
    when  BO_WEEKOFF_MASTER.week_off_day ='7' then 'Saturday' 
    else '' 
end **"week_off_day"**,
```

where i made error,
thank u

Comment: Please re-format your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? explain a little bit.

Comment: i am converting SQL query into Oracle query ...

Comment: which part you want to replace?

Comment: sql "word=case ....end" into Oracle " case.....end word "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capturing groups.

```
Regex.Replace(word , @"(\w+)=(case.*?\bend\b)", @"$2 ""$1""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tU5oL3/1)